# In ArrayList DB Data coming Empty from mysql servlets

Tags: java, mysql, json, servlets, arraylist

```
public static  ArrayList<Register> validateUser( String uname, String password)throws Exception 
{

    ArrayList<Register> login = new ArrayList<Register>();
    try 
    {
        con = establishConnection();
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT uname,password FROM login WHERE uname = ? ");
        pstmt.setString(1,uname);
        //pstmt.setString(2, password);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next())
        {

            Register reg = new Register();
            reg.setUname(rs.getString(uname));
            reg.setPassword(rs.getString(password));
            login.add(reg);
            System.out.println("password is "+rs.getString(2)+" username is "+rs.getString(1));
            if(rs.getString(2).equals(password))
            {

            }

        }
        else
            return login;
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try 
        {
            if(pstmt!=null)
                pstmt.close();
            if(con != null)
                con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return login;

}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {


     String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
     String password = request.getParameter("password");

     PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
     if(userName == null)
     {
        out.println("The userName you entered is wrong");
     }
     if(password ==  null)
     {
        out.println("Wrong password");
     }



     //Get the DB connection Validation here 

     String feeds = null;

     try {
         ArrayList<Register> login = null;
        if(Connector.validateUser(userName,password) != null)
         {
            out.println("Login successfull !!!");
            out.print("The userName is "+userName+" pasword is "+password);


            Gson gson = new Gson();
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(Connector.validateUser(userName,password)));
            out.println(Connector.validateUser(userName,password));
            feeds = gson.toJson(Connector.validateUser(userName,password));


         }
         else
         {
            out.println("Authentication Failed Boss!!!");
         }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

I need to convert db data into json . I am getting empty array . 
sendmail call the arraylist and display data in json format.
Any one help on this.

This is the output of the program
Login successfull !!!
The userName is example pasword is example[]

Comment: While the structure of the code is a bit messy, I can't see any reason as to why the arrayList returned by the validateUser() method would be empty. I would suggest you check whether or not the field on your db table are actually called 'uname' and 'password'.

Comment: Also note that the condition if(Connector.validateUser(userName,password) != null) will never be false